# what is the meaning of 'a' and 'h1' in '#main-navigation h1 a'

Tags: html, css

As the title suggests, I want to know the meaning of a and h1 in '#main-navigation h1 a'. Here is the code:

```
#main-navigation {
  ...
}

#main-navigation a {     
  ...
}

#main-navigation a:hover,
#main-navigation a:active {
  color: #cf79f1;
}

#main-navigation h1 a:hover,
#main-navigation h1 a:active {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: h1 is <h1> tag in html a is tag <a> in html.... i'll suggest to read some tutorial about css selectors

Comment: <a> and <h1> elements in your html.

Comment: It refers to the DOM / HTML structure. It means inside the element with id `main-navigation` you have an `<h1>` element and inside the `<h1>` element you have an anchor tag `<a>`. You specific the styling more precisely, because you don't want to style all title or anchor tags, only the ones inside the main-navigation element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space between tags in CSS mean whatever is after the space is a child of the previous element.
Example:

```
#main-navigation a
```

means: apply following styles to all `a` elements within `#main-navigation`

Answer (score 0):

`a` tag is for URL linking and stuff.

`h1` tag represent heading

More here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a